# Is it possible to get the url without the domain name /localhost name or the

Tags: laravel

The following route:

```
route('schools.student',$user->id);
```

will return:

```
localhost:8402/api/v1/schools/student/3
```

Is it possible to just return the url without localhost:8402?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a third parameter to the `route()` helper for relative urls.

```
route('schools.student', $user->id, false);
```